# When can one bound the Hilbert transform on the torus in $L^1$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

If $f$ is a function on $\mathbb T$ then the conjugate $\tilde f$ of $f$ satisfies Zygmund's bound

$$\int |\tilde f|\leq A \int |f|\log(e+|f|)+B.$$

I am curious if there are any conditions where one can guarantee something like

$$\int |\tilde f|\leq \epsilon\int |f|\log(e+|f|)$$

for small $\epsilon>0$.